# Python web crawling is throwing connection errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I have the following Python code intended for web crawling, When I try to run this one, It is throwing me the following error. **Code** :

```
import lxml.html
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url1='http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html?class=11;filter=advanced;orderby=runs;'
url2 ='page='
url3 ='size=200;template=results;type=batting'
url5 = ['http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html?class=11;filter=advanced;orderby=runs;size=200;template=results;type=batting']
for i in range(2,3854):
     url4 = url1 + url2 + str(i) + ';' + url3
     url5.append(url4)
for page in url5:
        source_code = requests.get(page, verify=False)
    # just get the code, no headers or anything
        plain_text = source_code.text
    # BeautifulSoup objects can be sorted through easy
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "lxml")
        for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'data-link'}):
                href = "https://www.espncricinfo.com" + link.get('href')
                title = link.string  # just the text, not the HTML
                source_code = requests.get(href)
                plain_text = source_code.text
                soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "lxml")
# if you want to gather information from that page
                for item_name in soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'ciPlayerinformationtxt'}):
                             print(item_name.string)
```

**The error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests-2.8.0-py3.4.egg\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 559, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests-2.8.0-py3.4.egg\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 345, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests-2.8.0-py3.4.egg\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 782, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests-2.8.0-py3.4.egg\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 266, in connect
    match_hostname(cert, self.assert_hostname or hostname)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\ssl.py", line 285, in match_hostname
    % (hostname, ', '.join(map(repr, dnsnames))))
ssl.CertificateError: hostname 'www.espncricinfo.com' doesn't match either of 'a248.e.akamai.net', '*.akamaihd.net', '*.akamaihd-staging.net', '*.akamaized.net', '*.akamaized-staging.net'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests-2.8.0-py3.4.egg\requests\adapters.py", line 369, in send
    timeout=timeout   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests-2.8.0-py3.4.egg\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 588, in urlopen
    raise SSLError(e) requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: hostname 'www.espncricinfo.com' doesn't match either of 'a248.e.akamai.net', '*.akamaihd.net', '*.akamaihd-staging.net', '*.akamaized.net', '*.akamaized-staging.net'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/intplayername.py", line 23, in <module>
    source_code = requests.get(href)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests-2.8.0-py3.4.egg\requests\api.py", line 69, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests-2.8.0-py3.4.egg\requests\api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests-2.8.0-py3.4.egg\requests\sessions.py", line 471, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests-2.8.0-py3.4.egg\requests\sessions.py", line 579, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests-2.8.0-py3.4.egg\requests\adapters.py", line 430, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: hostname 'www.espncricinfo.com' doesn't match either of 'a248.e.akamai.net', '*.akamaihd.net', '*.akamaihd-staging.net', '*.akamaized.net', '*.akamaized-staging.net'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's due to the misconfiguration of the https certificates on the site you want to crawl. As a workaround, you can turn off certificate checking in the `requests` library

```
requests.get(href, verify=False)
```

Please be advised, that it's not a recommended practice when you work with sensitive information.

Comment: Thanks. I made the changes as you suggested and I get the following warnings.

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests-2.8.0-py3.4.egg\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 789
    InsecureRequestWarning)
InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html

Comment: Lower on the page you can find how to deactivate warnings: https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#disabling-warnings